# Config file XDT transformation InsertIfMissing is skipping children

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-config, nuget, transformation

I am having trouble doing config transform, adding app settings on nuget package install where element `appSetting` may or may not exist.

**What I want to happen:**

- `appSetting` element does not exist

  - Insert `appSetting` element and its children
- `appSetting` element exist

  - Insert children if missing

I only get one or the other to work, but not both occasions.

**web.config.install.xdt**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" >
    <add key="Swagger.Contact.Name" value="Some Name" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
    <add key="Swagger.Contact.Email" value="some@email.address" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

## Example 1

**web.config** BEFORE

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="51200" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

`appSettings` element **not present** before transformation.

**web.config** AFTER

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="51200" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Swagger.Contact.Name" value="Some Name" />
    <add key="Swagger.Contact.Email" value="some@email.address" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

## Example 2

**web.config** BEFORE

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="51200" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Other.Key" value="With Some Value" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

`appSettings` element **present** before transformation.

**web.config** AFTER

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="51200" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Other.Key" value="With Some Value" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Nothing happens in example 2 as the `appSettings` element already exist, I would like it to still evaluate its child elements and insert those if they do not exist, but it seems they are just ignored. Is there any other value for the attribute `xdt:Transform` I can use, or any other hacks to work around this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem quite a while back. The workaround I applied was to have two entries with `<appSettings>` in the XDT file, one to check if its absent and if yes, then go ahead and insert it. The other was for the scenario when the `<appSettings>` element was already present. Here is short snippet to help you with your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <appSettings xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    </appSettings>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="Swagger.Contact.Name" value="Some Name" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
      <add key="Swagger.Contact.Email" value="some@email.address" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I thought about this but didn't try, Ill do that when I get the time, as I changed to doing XML transformation where the files are named like `web.config.transform`. However it seems to insert duplicate entries so if this works well ill change to doing this in stead. :)

Comment: From the limited testing iv done it seems to work. :)